# Grails set System property for test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

Is it possible to directly set a System.property for a particular method of a Grails unit test class?

I've got a Filters class that blocks some actions if a system property is set in Config.groovy:

```
class MyFilters {
def filters = 
{
    if ('true'.equals(System.properties.getProperty('myProperty', 'false'))){
        writeFilter(controller: "myController", action: "update")
        {
            before =
            {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
                return false;
```

In MyControllerTests, I'm trying to implement a test for the filter:

```
void testMyFilter(){
    System.properties.setProperty('myProperty', 'true')
    withFilters(action:"update") {
        controller.update()
    }
    assert response.status ==  HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN
}
```

But the filter class is already mocked at this stage (using the default 'false' property value from Config) so the change of the property in the test has no effect.

Is there a way around this, or a way to force Grails to reload the Filters class after the prop is changed?  I can't change the default property in Config as the other controller tests will break, it's just for a particular environment where this prop will be set so I'd like the scenario covered by a test that checks the Filter will kick in.

Thanks.

Comment: Inevitably, I found out how to do it about a minute after I posted this.

Adding mockFilters(MyFilters) after the setProperty makes Grails rebuild the mocked filter with the updated property.  (Too new to self-answer, I'll close this issue when I can).

Comment: Please post you comment as an answer so this question may be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inevitably, I found out how to do it about a minute after I posted this. Adding mockFilters(MyFilters) after the setProperty makes Grails rebuild the mocked filter with the updated property.